# opengl rotate about world axes

Tags: opengl, rotation

Can someone with OpenGl experience please suggest a strategy to help me solve an issue I'm having with rotations?

Imagine a set of world coordinate xyz axes bolted to the center of the universe; that is, for purposes of this
discussion they do not move. I'm also doing no translations, and the camera is fixed, 
    to keep things simple. I have a cube centered at the origin and the intent is 
    that pressing the 'x', 'y', and 'z' keys will increment
a variable representing the number of degrees to rotate the cube *about the world xyz axes*. Each key press is 90° (you can imagine rotating a lego brick
in such a way), so pressing the 'x' key increments a float property RotXdeg:

RotXdeg += 90.0f;

Likewise for the pressing the 'y' and 'z' keys.

A naive way to implement<sup>[1]</sup>  this is:

```
   Gl.glPushMatrix(); 
    Gl.glRotatef(RotXdeg, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Gl.glRotatef(RotYdeg, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Gl.glRotatef(RotZdeg, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    Gl.glPopMatrix();
```

This of course has the effect or rotating the cube, *and its local xyz axes*, so the desired rotations about the *world* xyz axes have not been achieved.
(For those not familiar with OpenGl, this can be demonstrated by simply rotating 90&#176 about the x axis 
    &#8212 which causes the local y axis to be oriented along the world z axis &#8212
then a subsequent 90&#176 rotation about the y, which to the user appears to be a rotation 
    about the world z axis).
I believe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349575/opengl-matrix-rotation-quaternions) is asking for something similar, but the answer is not clear, and my understanding is that quaternions are just one way to solve the problem.
 It seems to me that 
    there should be a relatively straightforward solution, even if it is not
particularly efficient. I've spent hours trying various ideas, including creating my own rotation matrices and trying ways to multiply them with the modelview matrix, but to no
avail. (I realize matrix multiplication is not commutative, but I have a feeling that's not the problem.)

([1] By the way, I'm using the Tao OpenGl namespace; thanks to http://vasilydev.blogspot.com for the suggestion.)

[Code is here](http://home.earthlink.net/~cepeasley/RotationTest/RotateTest/)

Answer (score 0):

If the cube lies on (0,0,0) world and local rotations have the same effect. If the cube was in another position a 90deg rotation would result in a quarter-circular orbit around (0,0,0). It is unclear what you are failing to achieve, and i'd also advise against using the old immediate mode for matrix operations. Nevertheless a way to achieve world rotation that way is:
 - translate to (0,0,0)
 - rotate 90 degrees
 - translate back

Comment: To clarify: press the 'X' key, the cube rotates 90 degrees about the world X axis, as expected. Press the 'Y' key, the cube rotates 90 degrees about the world Z axis. That's the difficulty. My objective is when pressing the 'Y' key, the cube will rotate about the world Y axis, not world Z. (The world axes are shown with Y positive up). Also, good tip about old immediate mode.

Comment: I added axis labels and a a delay in the rotation (via Sleep) to make it clearer about which axis the cube is being rotated. And I added a word doc with screenshots to illustrate the difficulty. http://home.earthlink.net/~cepeasley/RotationTest_20150108/

Comment: I posted the latest source code at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/867804/D-Puzzle-with-OpenGl-and-Csharp